# how can I use sqlite3 as disk-backed O(n) hashtable?

Tags: database, sqlite, data-structures, hashtable, lookup

#### Problem:

I have `863,049,256` keys whose format is 34 character alphanumeric:

```
Z6DauUBtzw8p77MLxy7VWYCKN92JfKiCK
AJe8BJYnJHp9DDUrvGgFwmn5oBjhUSgowr
114VNKGsr9M4ogvwjz6ESNUqYdroGyht7r
etc..
```

I'd like to quickly check if a given key exists inside this dataset- preferably in O(1) time.

#### Attempted Solution:

I can't use the programming language's `set` / `hashset` / `unordered_set` / `hashtable`
because its too much data to load into memory.  So I've opted for a disk-based solution.
Using sqlite3, I load all the data into a table.  It looks something like this:

```
// load the database
SQL: create table if not exists hashtable (val varchar(34));
SQL: begin;

// add each value from a file
    SQL: insert into hashtable (val) values (var);
    SQL: ...

SQL: commit;
```

Then I check for the existence of an element using:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM hashtable WHERE val = 'val'
```

This is extremely slow.  Performance seems equivalent to me just grepping the original file.  SQL must be performing a scan?  I'm wondering if there is a more effecient way of doing this with sqlite, or if I've chosen the wrong tool for the job.

#### Additional information:

What I'm doing now, is I have a bloom filter in memory, and if it finds a collision, I do a slower SQL lookup to confirm the hit.  My "big data" use-case seems pretty common, so maybe there is a better database strategy or a different solution entirely.

Comment: Why not use an actual data structure meant for this, like LevelDB, or RocksDB (the newer, generally better version)? Both give you a key-value store that's analogous to a hashtable (but not implemented as one) optimized for that purpose.

Comment: To do this efficiently in SQLite, you'd need indexes on all relevant keys, and it's scanning on disk in `O(n)` time because that's how you told SQLite to generate your database. In this case, just setting the value to a primary key should suffice.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Yes, let me try a primary key then. A different choice in database sounds good also.  I wasn't familiar enough with sqlite to completely rule it out.  Sqlite seems very ubiquitous and so does my use-case, so I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: Finally, you're never getting `O(1)` time, because efficient on-disk data structures are typically B-trees or a LSM trees, which have `O(log n)` time, which is still efficient, but never `O(1)`. Actual hashmaps are not efficient for on-disk storage, due to a lack of data locality required. An efficient on-disk database though will often minimize the amount of I/O required and `O(log n)` complexity still scales very well. SQLite uses a B-tree, RocksDB uses an LSM tree.

Comment: Tokyo Cabinet, Kyoto Cabinet, gdbm, Berkeley DB, etc. offer disk-based hashtable key-value stores.